# Deploy a SSL HTTPS enabled site in XAMPP

Tags: php, ssl, https, xampp

Hi how to deploy a `SSL` enabled web site in XAMPP .. if im using `PHP` do i need to make any changes in the code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some specific changes you *might* need to make, from the top of my head:

- Secure Cookies
- Scheme and Port manipulation in URLs
- HTTP to HTTPS validations and redirections